# Find missing columns in data table

Tags: c#-4.0, datatable, ado.net

I am trying to fetch an XML response and I am filling the data table with the response.

My requirement is that I need to find missing columns from that data table.

Currently I am applying following logic:

```
if (!dtInstr.Columns.Contains("ABCD") && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dtInstr.Rows[0]["ABCD"].ToString())){
                missing_fields += "ABCD, "}
```

With the above logic, as the number of columns increase, I need to write extra logic which can be quite cumbersome.

Please let me know if there is a better way of achieving this.